# Updating SwiftUI View based on Observable in Preview

Tags: xcode, swiftui

Trying to implement a Login screen in SwiftUI. Based on other similar questions, I'm going the approach of using an Observable EnvironmentObject and a ViewBuilder in the main ContentView that reacts to that and displays the appropriate screen.

However, even though the property is updating as expecting the view never changes in Preview. Everything works fine when built and run in the Simulator but in Preview the change never happens.

Below is the code reduced to the smallest possible example in a single file (only missing passing the environment object in SceneDelegate, which doesn't affect Preview anyway).

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine

struct ContentView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var userAuth: UserAuth

    @ViewBuilder
    var body: some View {
        if !userAuth.person.isLoggedin {
                FirstView()
        } else {
                SecondView()
        }    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView().environmentObject(UserAuth())
    }
}




struct Person {
    var isLoggedin: Bool

    init() {
        self.isLoggedin = false
    }

}

class UserAuth: ObservableObject {
    @Published var person: Person

    init(){
        self.person = Person()
    }

  let didChange = PassthroughSubject<UserAuth,Never>()

  // required to conform to protocol 'ObservableObject'
  let willChange = PassthroughSubject<UserAuth,Never>()

  func login() {
    // login request... on success:
    willChange.send(self)
    self.person.isLoggedin = true
    didChange.send(self)
  }
}


struct SecondView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Second View!")
    }
}

struct SecondView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        SecondView().environmentObject(UserAuth())
    }
}

struct FirstView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var userAuth: UserAuth

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
                Button(action: {
                    self.userAuth.login()
                }) {
                    Text("Login")
                }
            Text("Logged in: " + String(self.userAuth.person.isLoggedin))
        }
    }
}

struct FirstView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        FirstView().environmentObject(UserAuth())
    }
}
```

EDIT: Based on the answer below, I've added the environment object to the interior views, but unfortunately the view still doesn't change in Preview mode.

Comment: It's there - you can see in `Debug Preview` that it goes into `SecondView` branch, so it is just a Preview refresh issue. I'd just ignore that.

Comment: @Asperi the problem is that in my real app, the views are in separate files so while looking at ContentView, if Preview isn't going to refresh it's useless for debugging login functionality.

Answer (score 2):

```
struct FirstView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        FirstView().environmentObject(UserAuth())
    }
}
```

environment object must be set in PreviewProvider as well

UPDATE
[image]

Comment: That seems reasonable! Unfortunately, it didn't make a difference, I'll update the question. Thanks!

Comment: I checked this in simple real project, it works for me on the simulator as well as on  the device.

Answer (score 1):

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var userAuth =  UserAuth () // @ObservedObject

    var body: some View {
    NavigationView{ // Navigation

        }.environmentObject(UserAuth) //.environmentObject
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView().environmentObject(UserAuth())

    }
}

struct SecondView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var userAuth: UserAuth // only EnvironmentObject
    var body: some View {
        Text("Second View!")
    }
}

struct SecondView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        SecondView().environmentObject(UserAuth()) 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue I was having with Canvas not giving previews is that my `ObservableObject` was reading from User Defaults

```
@Published var fName: String  = Foundation.UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "fName") ! 
    { didSet {
       Foundation.UserDefaults.standard.set(self.fName, forKey: "fName")
       }
    }
```

So works in simulator and on device but no Canvas Previews. I tried many ways to give Preview data to use since Preview can't read from `UserDefaults` (not a device), and realized I can put an initial/ default value if the UserDefault is not there:

```
@Published var fName: String  = Foundation.UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "fName") ?? "Sean" 
{ didSet {
    Foundation.UserDefaults.standard.set(self.fName, forKey: "fName")
       }
}
```

Now Preview/ Canvas is showing my view and I can continue coding with my Observable Object. The aim was to put in the Observable Object some default code to use.